# Need help creating typing speed game with time

Tags: c++

So I am fairly new to C++ and I am making a game for school, where you have to type a word before a set amount of time, and you only have 3 lives. In this case, 4 seconds. I am having problems making a timer, and stopping that timer when putting the correct answer. Here is what I have now:

```
string wordsOne [10];    
int life = 3;
int duration;

reset2:
duration = 0;

cout << "Type 'HACK'\n";

while (wordsOne[0] != "hack") {
    sleep(1);
    ++duration;

    if (duration == 4) {
        --life;
        cout << "You have " << life << " lives left!\n";

        if (life >= 1) {
            sleep(1);
            goto reset2;
        }

        else if (life < 1) {
            lost();
        }
    }
}

getline (cin, wordsOne[0]);

if (wordsOne[0] == "hack") {
    cout << "SUCCESS\n";
}
```

I know I know, I shouldn't use goto, but it was the most simple thing I could think of. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `std::chrono` library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono
there you can find everything you need for your timer

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your attempt is that you ran the timer to completion and *then* tried to input the value.  You can only separate your program logic like this if you use threads, and I hope you don't mind me highlighting that you are *not* ready for threading yet.

Good news: It's simpler than this.  You just take a time stamp before input and a time stamp after.  Then you can calculate out how much time elapsed.  No need to make it complicated.

The code below demonstrates this, but doesn't solve your problem directly.  The rest of the program logic is up to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    const std::string target = "hack";
    const std::chrono::milliseconds time_limit( 4000 );

    std::cout << "Type '" << target << "' - you can't lose" << std::endl;
    std::string input;

    auto time_begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    getline( std::cin, input );
    auto time_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto elapsed_milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        time_end - time_begin );

    if( input == target && elapsed_milli <= time_limit )
    {
        std::cout << "u winnar" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! You don't realise how much you saved me. Just wondering how difficult it would be to start to learn or to get into threading?